# Firebase kotlin error while reloading user and checking isEmailVerified

Tags: android, email, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm trying to reload user after the activity is reloaded so that it follows to another activity after user displays it another time and emaila was verified but I got error like 'Error:(41, 29) Smart cast to 'FirebaseUser' is impossible, because 'user' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure'
can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    var  user: FirebaseUser? = null
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.reload()?.addOnSuccessListener {
        void ->
             user =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    }
    if(user != null && user.isEmailVerified ){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Inside of if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the user evaluation to inside the callback, otherwise it won't wait the callback to return to evaluate it. Like this:

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.reload()?.addOnSuccessListener {
            void ->
            var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

            if(user != null && user.isEmailVerified ){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Inside of if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
        }

    }
```